# lower and upper block matrices in $SL(m+n,\mathbb R)/SL(m+n,\mathbb Z)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-groups

Let $\begin{pmatrix}
P_1 & 0 \\
P_3 & P_4 
\end{pmatrix}$ be a matrix in $SL(m+n,\mathbb R)$ with $P_1$ an $m\times m$ matrix, $P_3$ an $n\times m$ matrix and $P_4$ an $n\times n$ matrix (the block for $P_2$ is zero). In the quotient homegeneous space $SL(m+n,\mathbb R)/SL(m+n,\mathbb Z)$

I wonder if $\begin{pmatrix}
P_1 & 0 \\
P_3 & P_4 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
I_m & A \\
0 & I_n 
\end{pmatrix}SL(m+n, \mathbb Z) = \begin{pmatrix}
I_m & B \\
0 & I_n 
\end{pmatrix} SL(m+n, \mathbb Z)$, where $A,B$ are real $m\times n$ matrices, would imply that $$\begin{pmatrix}
I_m & A \\
0 & I_n 
\end{pmatrix}SL(m+n, \mathbb Z) = \begin{pmatrix}
I_m & B \\
0 & I_n 
\end{pmatrix} SL(m+n, \mathbb Z)$$
as two left cosets? (or in other words $A-B$ is a matrix with integer entries)

I am inclined to believe this is correct but can't prove it formally.

Answer (score 1):

No. $\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
3 & 1/2 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1/2 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}SL(2, \mathbb Z) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} SL(2, \mathbb Z)$.
But

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1/2 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}SL(2, \mathbb Z) \ne \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} SL(2, \mathbb Z).$$